# Prolog returns a false value?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to learn Prolog but I've stuck at this little problem,
when I compile this

```
score('jack',50).
score('smith',80).
score('justin',50).
score('sami',70).
score('jack',80).
passing(X):-score(X,Y),Y>=60.
failing(X):-score(X,Y),Y<60.
better(X,Y):-score(X,A),score(Y,B),A>B.
```

and then I try

```
better(X,'jack')
```

in order to see whose score is better than jacks, it gives me this result

```
X = smith ;
X = sami ;
X = jack ;
false.
```

I just don't get why it's returning false? can you please help me? thanks !

Comment: `false` in prolog means "no more solutions". Perfectly normal.

Comment: but when i omit jack's second score it doesn't return false !

Comment: @Programmer because then there are values of (X,A) for which A > 50.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't explicit on that point. It means "no more solutions" after having tried the last choice point in the code that failed, although prior choices may have succeeded. So in Prolog, when you do a query, it checks a variety of solutions through your clauses and yields results. After each presented solution, if there are remaining choice points, it checks for more. If there are no more, then it will return `false` (or `no` or similar). If the last solution succeeded without any remaining choice points, then it won't show `false` or `no`.